# What is the easiest way to check if SPI is correctly initialized on STM32?

Tags: rust, stm32, spi

I have STM32F103C8 chip and a LED display that is connected via SPI1 (PA7-PA4) interface. I want to ensure that my initialization code is correct before starting to write the rest of the code. Is there a way to check if my initialization code is correct?

P. S. I'm trying to code in Rust for STM32, that's why I have to write rather low-level code and initialization is a bit harder than in C with high-level STM32 libraries.

Comment: oscilloscope...

Comment: @old_timer even better $10 logic analyser from aliexpress or ebay :)

Comment: @KolesnichenkoDS `I'm trying to code in Rust for STM32, that's why I have to write rather low-level code and initialization is a bit harder than in C with high-level STM32 libraries.` Very interesting theory. I for example only do the bare register programming with no libraries. Do you know more low level programming?

Comment: I think the OP is combining the two focusing on C and libraries as a set. I recommend learning to program the part directly in C a language well used for such a thing (with no libraries).  THEN once you know how to control the part, try to build a backend infrastructure (C and asm) to get a lesser used language for a target like this working.

Comment: @PeterJ yep, generally that works  99.99999999 percent of the time but every so often you need the scope, i2c in particular more than SPI.  The logic analyzer cant show you who is driving the bus and when they took over (with a wired-or bus like i2c) where the scope can.  I was going to wait and see what the response was (I dont have a scope) then suggest a logic analyzer but you beat me to it...with out one or the other (or a chip simulator which who here has access to the  source code for this chip) you cant check if it is correctly initialized.

Comment: @old_timer yes but actually I2C probably every designed has used and programmed so many times and got enough experience so even multimeter is sufficient for debugging :). But seriously as I did not any analog designs for years (and to design analog parts of my devices I  hire someone as I newer used to be good in it) - I have turned on my scope last time maybe a year ago. But I use very often LA as I can record and decode longer transmissions - it helps me a lot especially for difficult to diagnose problems (like it works 10 minutes and dies and similar)

Comment: its more of a case of figuring out the peripheral's protocol or whatever that isnt working, you can see on the scope the small step in the ground when one device takes over from the other, subtle differences that a logic analyzer cannot see.  Most of the time sure you dont need this, usually when the docs are garbage and you are hacking your way through, or a board was built with the wrong value pull up or missing one or whatever and the scope tells you instantly (but an analyzer wouldnt).  for figuring out the peripheral in the mcu, analyzer is fine.

Comment: @old_timer my one takes those subtle changes as well into consideration :).  Discussion is pointless as the both are extremely useful devices and they should be in the designer drawer. If someone asks me "how good oscilloscope should I buy (or LA) I always answer as good you can afford :)

Comment: @PeterJ I just meant that I cannot use higher-level abstractions, that C libraries provide :)

Comment: @KolesnichenkoDS  I do not know what you mean. EOD for me

Comment: @PeterJ and thanks for the advice, I've decided to buy a logic analyzer. Maybe you'll move your comment to the answer?

Answer (score 0):

- Use logic analyzer to see what is going on when you send your data.
- Test with simple 74hc595  serial-in parallel-out shift register. It has SPI input. You can put leds on outputs or just measure voltages to make sure that data is right.